# CSS Grid use the rest of free space for all elements between

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

how can I achieve in CSS-GRID something like "all elements between"? Is it possible to do that without defining all these areas for every element?

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="element"><a class="active" href="#home">A</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">B</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">C</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">D</a></div>
</div>

#menu
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 25% <all_elements> 25%;
    grid-template-areas: "... <all_elements> ...";      
}
```

Or do I actually have to do something like

```
<div container>
    placeholder
    div menu
    placeholder
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no possibility to select inbetween elements in CSS in general. Maybe you can do something with `repeat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS grid you could do something like:

```css
#menu
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); 
    padding: 0 25%;
}

.element {
  grid-column: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="element"><a class="active" href="#home">A</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">B</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">C</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">D</a></div>
</div>
```

When you have an unspecified amount of columns you can also use:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
```

Some more information about these functions:

https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Or even

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');

menu.style.setProperty( '--columns', elements.length );
```

```css
#menu
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr); 
    padding: 0 25%;
}

.element {
  grid-column: auto;
}

:root {
  --columns: 4; /* Default amount of columns */
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="element"><a class="active" href="#home">A</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">B</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">C</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">D</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">E</a></div>
    <div class="element"><a href="#home">F</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with flexbox:

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid;
}
#menu > * {
  flex:1;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#menu:before,
#menu:after {
  content:"";
  width:25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="element"><a class="active" href="#home">A</a></div>
  <div class="element"><a href="#home">B</a></div>
  <div class="element"><a href="#home">C</a></div>
  <div class="element"><a href="#home">D</a></div>
</div>
```